# How I listen soft keyboard event on mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile

In one of my webapp page, I place a input and when I focus the input the soft keyboard pop.Then how can I know the user touch the 'enter' key?

Comment: Use event.keyCode to check which key was pressed

Comment: I solve the problem by code follow:

Comment: `function(event) { var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which; if(keyCode === 13) {trigger my function} } `

Comment: and I listen keypress and ontouchend

Answer (score 0):

event.keyCode should be used to know the input keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

For android use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER to detect pressing enter